# Where are all the gambling locations?

Tags: borderlands-2

I know there's at least three gambling locations.  Two are located in Sanctuary (in Mad Moxxi's place), and 1 other is found in the Holy Spirits (highlands).  I'm curious if there's actually any other gambling machines out in Pandora.

Where can I find other gambling locations?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are 8 slot machines currently spread across Pandora.

- 2 are located at Moxxi's bar in Sanctuary
- 1 is located in The Old Dahlwell Oasis (The Dust) inside of the abandoned gas station
- 1 is located at the Holy Spirits bar in Overlook (Highlands)
- 4 are located at the Badass Crater Bar.

  - 2 allow you to gamble money
  - 2 allow you to gamble Torgue Tokens

Further, you will sometimes stumble upon [One-armed bandits](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Goliath#Types). These enemies carry slot machines on their back.  When killed, they will fall over and the slot machine will be playable.

For anyone unable to find them, picture overload below.

- Moxxi's bar in Sanctuary (hopefully easy to find)

[image: Moxxi's in Sanctuary]

- Old Dahlwell Oasis

[image: Gas Station Location]
[image: Inside the Gas Station]

- Holy Spirits

[image: Outside the Holy Spirits]
[image: Inside the Holy Spirits]

- Badass Crater Bar

[image: Money Slots]
[image: Token Slots]

Comment: Do One Armed Bandits reliably spawn at the same locations? They seem to be slightly cheaper.

Comment: @Annan I'd bet that there is a fixed subset of locations that they *can* spawn, but they are likely rare spawns. I couldn't find any reliable information about all the places they can spawn, but in [this thread](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/638784-borderlands-2/64143612) someone says they found one while completing the Flesh-Stick quest (other places are also listed). I can personally confirm that they can spawn in flesh-stick's camp, but that is the only location I remember seeing one (I've seen a few, that's the only one I remember).

Comment: @Annan In the end, though, I wouldn't use one-armed bandits for farming. Gambling on one machine at a time is such a painfully slow process I don't consider it worth my time. At level 50, I have so much money it would take me a considerable amount of time to gamble it all away. At Moxxxi's bars (Badass Crater and Sanctuary), you can at least gamble two at a time. If you have enough Torgue Tokens, you can even play 4 at a time in the Badass Crater Bar.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the newest DLC, Mr. Torgue's Campaign of Slaughter, there are two gambling machines in the Badass Crater Bar. These two are accompanied by two special Torgue Slot Machines that only accept Torgue Tokens, a currency that you pick up in the new DLC.

Answer (score 3):

You can occasionally come across enemies with a gambling machine on their back - when you kill them you can play the machine - that's the only other 'location' I know about, but I'm only up to the Holy Spirits tavern myself

Comment: Do the machines function the exact same way the normal ones do?

Comment: @Retrosaur - yep, exactly the same, except they're lying down and you'll have to jump up onto the machine to see the reel's spin

Answer (score 1):

I have run into three one-armed bandits in playthrough 1 (and zero in playthrough 2 sadly).  The first was in Fleshstick's camp, the second was in The Fridge (just before the cliff above the cristalisks), and the third was in Sawtooth Cauldren while doing the side mission for raising the flags (he was in the last flag camp).  I have found the cost of the slot machines the one-armed bandits carry to be the same as all the others and the odds of a useful payout or a legendary to be exactly the same as well.

The cost of a spin on any slot machine appears to scale to storyline progress and playthrough. So a lv 50 that was power-leveled from 1 to 50 in another players campaign but never completed their own campaign in playthrough 1 will be able to play the slots in sanctury when they first arrive for next to nothing whereas a lv 20 that would likely have only just reached The Fridge or perhaps sanctuary after it starts flying, would be paying upwards of 400 or 500 a spin (possibly more it's been a while since i was lv 20).  By the end of playthrough 2 it's in the thousands of dollars a spin and very rarely are you going to find something better than what you have gotten from killing bosses.

Also, the level of the guns you get from payouts is scaled to your storyline progress so if you take that power-leveled character and sit at the machine in sanctuary (in your barely started storyline) and are lucky enough to get the 3 vault-hunters/borderlands symbols; the legendary gun you get will be about level 7. Not exactly useful to a level 50 character.

As for odds of a payout (especially a useful one); there are many videos on youtube that suggest one or another having better or worse odds, but as someone who has played all of them for upwards of 10 hours each; the odds on any machine are about the same.  Sometimes you will be lucky and get 2 eridium jackpots in a row, sometimes you will get a granade 10 spins in a row.  Overall you are most likely just going to get tons of useless vendor fodder guns (Vendor Fodder: an item only useful for selling at an ammo/med/gun machine), a mess of different player skins, and some of your cash back.

Comment: Since i just joined i'm not sure how to improve my numbers but if it works on likes or thumbs ups so something and you found this post helpful please help me improve my ranking/numbers or however it works.

Comment: Hi Brandon, asking for upvotes is [not something we encourage on the Stack Exchange sites.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63439/begging-for-votes)  If you post something good, and people find it helpful, they'll upvote it of their own accord.

Comment: You may also want to carefully read the question - are you answering the question posed there?  (Where are the gambling locations?)  While this is interesting information, this is a Q&A site, so we try to keep the answers directly related to the question at the top of the page.  You've clearly got some good effort invested here, so keep it up and I'm sure you'll have tons of rep in no time :)

Comment: Thank you for the advice, i will not go looking for upvotes again. i looked as the faq portion of the site and have learned a bit more of the do's and do nots and will do my best to abide by them. and thank you for the kind words as well.