# Can I gamble if I can't get to Sanctuary?

Tags: borderlands-2

I'm at the part in the story line where

> Sanctuary is gone.

I'm playing with someone so I don't want to level my character past them, but I'd like to kill some time and gamble for some better weapons. How can I do this when I can't get to Sanctuary?

Edit:
Here's what I did -

> Overall, it doesn't take much time to get Sanctuary back if you just rush through. If you're not trying to keep pace with someone else, just push forward on the story-line and it will be back soon enough. Otherwise, and this is what I did first, you can hike to Overlook and gamble there. It's not as nice as Sanctuary though, and you wind up killing stuff along the way anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you *can* gamble without access to Sanctuary. Without considering DLC, there is one vending machine inside the abandoned gas station in The Old Dahlwell Oasis (The Dust) and one in the Holy Spirits bar in Overlook. See [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/95302/4775) for information on additional vending machines available in DLC locations.

As **APrough** mentions in his comment, with some luck you may find a [one-armed bandit](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Goliath#Types) to suit your gambling needs. If you find one, make sure to leash them near a vending machine before killing them. Otherwise selling unwanted items to continue gambling can be a real pain.

Comment: You also might get lucky enough to find a one-armed bandit, most likely in the Fridge.

Comment: @APrough Very good point. I'll add that to my answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't gamble when you can't get to Sanctuary.

If you are playing True Vault Hunter mode (which is unlocked after you finish the game for the first time), you can always switch back to the Normal mode playthrough and game there, although then the items you get are probably limited to level 30.

Another option would be to join another friend's game where you can get to Sanctuary.

Comment: I saw another answer that lists a few other places that contain slot machines. Are these much further in the storyline?

Comment: If you mean the other answer listing Moxxie's Bar in the Torgue DLC, as it said it will take a while to get to that point. Plus then you'd still be ahead of your friend, since presumably neither of you have started that DLC yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Torgue DLC you can gamble in Moxie's Bar, but you'll have to do *even more* missions before you can unlock that I believe. You won't advance the main story but will likely gain a level or two.

The only places in the whole game as of now are Sanctuary and the Badass Crater Bar.

Answer (score 0):

There is a slot machine you can gamble with in the 'Irish' pub in Overlook. You travel here in the same part of the story.